# @twilio/voice-sdk@2.1.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 12". Got "10.19.0"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, twilio

I am getting the error: @twilio/voice-sdk@2.1.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 12". Got "10.19.0" How do I fix this?

[image]

my current node version is `v16.13.2`

Comment: check your `package.json` if you have a node version restriction in there as well

Comment: @apokryfos there is no have any version restriction.

Comment: Try running `which npm` and then use that result to do e.g. `node /usr/bin/npm install` in case npm is using the wrong node version (where `/usr/bin/npm` is the result of `which npm`)

Comment: it's showing the same version `/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/npm`.

Comment: Try running `node /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/npm install`

Comment: `node /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/npm install` didn't working getting same error

Comment: Then it's likely one of your other dependencies strictly requires node 10 while the others require node >=12 causing conflicts

Comment: Do you have an [`"engines"` key set in your app's `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#engines)?

Comment: Also, looks like you were originally using yarn, there are suggestions around to ignore the engines restriction by running `yarn install --ignore-engines`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is what helped:

```bash
sudo yarn install --ignore-engines
```